# Iterate DOM elements with phpQuery

Tags: php, dom, curl

I'm fetching an external page via curl and storing it in a variable. Then I need to parse all the 'a' tags in the document and modify it. To do so I need to loop through each 'a' tag. My current code:

```
    <?php
    require 'phpQuery/phpQuery/phpQuery.php';
    $url = $_GET['url'];

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/1.0");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result= curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $curlUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/curl2.php?url='.$url;
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument ($result);



    //loop here 
    $href = $doc->find('a')->attr('href');      
    if (preg_match($url,$href))
    {
        //do something
    }       
    $doc->find('#nav li a')->attr('href', $curlUrl.$href);
    //end loop


    echo '<base href="'.$_GET['url'].'"/>';
    echo $doc;
    ?>
```

In jquery there is the .each() function which does what I need and iterates through each 'a' tag. Is there something similar in phpquery or other php DOM methods to iterate through the document and modify each 'a' tag?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I used phpQuery, but your should be able to just use a foreach

```
foreach ($doc['a'] as $link) {
    $href = pq($link)->attr('href');
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but is the first line of code valid? I'm still new to php but is it possible to have two assignment operators in a single statement? what does the two assignments do?

Comment: Yeah you can, but in my answer it was a typo :) I was editing just as you commented.  My edit is based on some live code using phpQuery, I went to check it just to be sure.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. The pulled external content is stored as an object or an array. Which can then be directly accessed by the foreach function. Is pq equivalent to .this in javascript?

Comment: phpQuery allows array syntax to be used to find selectors in the content like #id, .class, element etc.  No pq is not equivelent of JS this.  It is a helper method in phpQuery that returns a phpQuery object that will understand further method calls on it